# Proguard output JAR file cannot be executed

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation, proguard

I've used Proguard to obfuscate my .JAR file. After obfuscation, the JAR file was not executing. On decompiling the obfuscated code, I found my main method was renamed.

Original code :

```
public static transient void main(String args[])
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new  Object()     /* anonymous class not found */
    class _anm1 {}
    );
}
```

Obfuscated code :

```
public static transient void a(String as[])
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new aa());
}
```

I unchecked all the options in obfuscation tab, but still no LUCK !
Any help ?

Comment: Can you post your proguard setup?

Answer (score 1):

By default, ProGuard renames or even removes all classes, fields, and methods in your code. You need to preserve the entry points of your code. In the case of a simple application, the entry points are the main class and its main method. In your ProGuard configuration:

```
-keep public class mypackage.MyMain {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

See the ProGuard manual > [Introduction](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html)

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [A typical application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#application)

Comment: I was using GUI version of Proguard. Do I need to edit this in configuration script ?

Comment: The GUI has a corresponding setting "Keep Applications" in the "Shrinking" tab. It is set by default.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested that, but I read that Proguard deleted unused classes.
Try that way - maybe it helps:

```
public static transient void main(String args[])
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new  Object()     /* anonymous class not found */
    class _anm1 {}
    );
    new _anm1();
}
```

Comment: how can a class containing main be considered as "unused" ?

Comment: Because no object of _anm1 class was ever created.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution (by hit and trial)

Actually Progaurd obfuscates in such a way that all methods are renamed to a,b,c and such simpler names. This happens for all methods including main method (as shown above in question). So open the obfuscated class (using decompiler, I prefer Cavaj Decompiler) after extracting from jar file (using Winrar or similar utility). Edit the file and rename main method back to

`public static void main(String[]args)`

Save the edited class file, it would be saved as a Java file. Compile it, and put it back in JAR file (using Winrar).

Now execute the class file. If the class file doesn't work, edit your Manifest because classes (and sometimes packages) are renamed after obfuscation and such changes are not reflected in Manifest.

This worked for me, comment if anybody is still facing any problem.